# Core Data deleteObject sets all properties to nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm a little new CoreData.

When I call `deleteObject()` with `object` on my `NSManagedContext` object, its setting all the properties in the `object` to nil. Is there anyway for me to avoid this? I don't want to be nullified.

My project is in Swift.

Comment: `deleteObject()` is supposed to remove `object` completely.

Comment: @vadian: I understand that. But is there anyway to just delete it from the nsmanagedcontext and not its own memory?

Comment: What's the purpose for that? When the object has been deleted it's gone.

Comment: Why would you want to delete an object and keep it in memory anyway? Instead, couldn't you just cut all the relations of that object, but keep it in the context instead?

Comment: Explain why, what will you do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of CoreData. It's a way of managing a persistent store, which means that whatever you tell your context, is absolute. So if you `deleteObject()`, that object gets prepared for deletion and you're not supposed to touch it anymore.

Instead, you want some kind of mirror object, that allows you to create a new copy of the NSManagedObject for in-memory use. You could do it like this;

```
struct MirrorManaged {
    var text: NSString
}

class Managed: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var text: NSString

    func copyToMemory() -> MirrorManaged {
        return MirrorManaged(text: self.text)
    }
}
```